# how can i access a global variable in a python inner class

Tags: python, oop, scope, global-variables, peewee

Am new to Python. I am working on a project using Peewee ORM and Bottle.

My models.py file defines my models. My "db" variable is defined in my main file(index.py). I would like to access that same "db" instance using a global in the BaseModel Meta inner class below.

```
from peewee import *
import settings

class BaseModel(Model):
    global db
    class Meta:
        global db
        database = db

class Account(BaseModel):
    created_ip = CharField(null=True)
    created_on = DateTimeField()
```

I get the error below when i try to run the code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 11, in <module>
    from models import Account, Crawl, Site, Url
  File "/api/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class BaseModel(Model):
  File "/api/models.py", line 7, in BaseModel
    class Meta:
  File "/api/models.py", line 9, in Meta
    database = db
NameError: name 'db' is not defined
```

Can i access the global "db" in the inner class, is there an easier way to use the global "db" instance in another file?

Thank you

Comment: You haven't assigned `db` a value in that module. Globals are per-module.

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand what you are saying. If I define a global in one file I won't be able to use its value in another file even though I have imported the defining file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't define your `db` database instance inside the main file. Keep it with your models in the `models.py`. And, according to the [documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#creating-a-database-connection-and-tables), it is recommended to have a *base model* that would have the `database` "meta" attribute defined:

```
db = SqliteDatabase('my_app.db')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class User(BaseModel):
    username = CharField()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i had that initially, but my application has grown to include a manager.py file where i also need to use the db instance, i also have this question for sharing my redis instance across code files as well.

Comment: @user964491 okay, thanks, then, have the `db` imported from this manager: `from manager import db`. In any case, using `global` is definitely not the way to go.

Comment: in the code snippet i am importing the "db" instance variable from the settings.py file, for now, i don't want to pass in the db instance everywhere i need it, plus the peewee documentation does not explain how i can pass the db instance directly to the model classes or if i can pass it to the constructor on the BaseModel class, i understand it is not a best practice, but i am not asking about best practices i am asking if it is possible, thank you for your answer though

Comment: i will accept your answer. thanks again. i ended up keeping my db instance scoped to the models.py file and the redis instance variable scoped to the store.py. the way i was able to pass the config data structure around was by implementing a config.py file and creating a Config class with a getter function that will make sure that the config.json file only gets loaded once in a global within the config.py file